# What makes a statement stronger than another?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

So I have some questions about what makes one statement stronger than another. First, I was asked to show which statement was stronger, just by saying it was one or the other:

> "Manchester United is the best Football team in England"

Or

> "...in Europe."

My work on this has since been graded, though I can't tell if my answer "...in England" was correct or not.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement *Manchester United is the best Football team in Europe* is much stronger than the statement *Manchester United is the best Football team in England*. Imagine a very bad year for England in which every team in England was worse than every team on the Continent. In that situation even the best team in England wouldn’t really be very good.

To put it a little differently, it’s easier to be the best team in England than to be the best team in Europe. Thus, when you say that Manchester United are the best team in Europe, you’re saying a lot more than when you say only that they’re the best team in England: you’re making a stronger statement. An even stronger statement would be that they’re the best team in the world. A weaker statement would be that they’re the best Premier League team in Manchester: for that they need only be better than Manchester City. (Which at the moment they are not.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @TheAtomicPeter: My pleasure!